# How to create facebook page with PHP or CURL?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

I have tested the code and it doesn't work.

This is my code to create the Facebook page, but it doesn't work (appId and secret are valid..).

Here is my actual code:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => FB_APPID,
            'secret' => FB_SKEY,
            'cookie' => true,
            'allowSignedRequest' => false
        ));

$t = $facebook->getAccessToken();


$file = 'A0HM1-800.png';
$arrData = array(
    'name' => 'Test Event',
    'start_time' => '2015-07-04', //ISO-8601 format - With Time  -     2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700
    //'end_time' => '', //optional
    'description' => 'Lvsty do Test-Event',
    'location' => 'Lvstydo', //Just a name
    'location_id' => '103091806397289', //place id - inserts a link to place fb page
    'ticket_url' => 'url', //URL to buy a ticket for the event
    'no_feed_story' => FALSE, //TRUE = dont display on page 
    'access_token' => $t,
    'picture' => '@'. realpath($file),
    );
$createUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/events';


$test = fbcurl($createUrl, 'POST', $arrData); //Returns the event id

echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';

function fbcurl($url, $method, $fields = array(), $auth = array()){

foreach($fields as $key => $value){
    if(!is_string($value)){
        $fields[$key] = json_encode($value);
    }
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
if(count($fields)>0){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields, null, '&'));

}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if($r!=''){
    $p = explode("\r\n\r\nHTTP/", $r);
    $p = (count($p) > 1 ? 'HTTP/' : '') . array_pop($p);
    list($h, $b) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $p, 2);
    return array('header' => $h, 'body' => $b);
}else{
    return array('header' => '', 'body' => 'error');
}
}
```

Error:

[image: error image]

Where is the error? I can't find it..

Comment: It is not possible to create pages using the API. But looking at your code it looks like you are trying to create an event

Comment: error is the picture.

Comment: Can  i use other way to create pages

Comment: Yes, go to facebook.com and do it manually